# How to receive parameters from another page

Tags: angular

I am doing a number calculation App where I want to pass parameters from one page to another but I get only the first value. what can I do to show the rest of the values in my component2?

I am getting the first value from the array in my page2 but I am not able to get other values which are coming in my console.log

component1.ts:-

```js
for (var i = 0; i < this.noQue; i++) { 
  var firstNum = Math.floor((Math.random() * divider));
  var secondNum = Math.floor((Math.random() * divider));

  if (this.operation == 1) {
    var answer = firstNum + secondNum;
  }
  else if (this.operation == 2) {
   var answer = firstNum - secondNum;
  }
  else if (this.operation == 3) {
    var answer = firstNum * secondNum;
  }

  this.answers.push(answer);
  this.answers1.push(answer);
  this.que.push({ firstNum, secondNum });
  this.ques.push({ firstNum, secondNum });
}

console.log('que---', this.que)
console.log('ans---', this.answers)

this.router.navigate(['/operation', { firstNum, secondNum, answer } ]);
```

Component2.ts:-

```js
export class OperationComponent implements OnInit {
  f:[];
  fa:[]; 
  answer:[]; 
  que:[]
  constructor(private route: ActivatedRoute) { } 

  ngOnInit() {
    this.f = parseInt(this.route.snapshot.paramMap.get("firstNum"));
    this.fa = parseInt(this.route.snapshot.paramMap.get("secondNum")); 
    this.answer = parseInt(this.route.snapshot.paramMap.get("answer")); 
  }
```

component2.html:-

```html
<div class="container"> 
  <h3 class="h2 text-center"> Grade </h3>
  <h3 class="h2 text-center"> Questions </h3> 
  <div class="card-block">
    <h4 class="card-title text-center"> {{f}} </h4> 
    <h4 class="card-title text-center"> +  {{fa}} </h4> 
    <p class="card-title h5 text-center"> _____</p> 
    <h4 class="card-title text-center"> {{answer}} </h4> 
    <button (click)="goBack()" [routerLink]="['']">go back</button>
  </div>
</div>
```

I expect the output as all the values displayed in my app

Comment: you do not connect pages you connect components. Angular is a Single Page Application. So I am not sure what you mean by a 2nd page do you mean a other Application? if the answer is not then you need to set a router

Comment: sorry, I am new to angular yes those are components

Comment: Then you have several options... 
1. A router -> https://angular.io/guide/router depending how far are the components from each other
2. Events with EventEmiter
3. Observables through a service.

Comment: Here I have passed the data using navigate but only the first value is shown on the second page

Answer (score 0):

One possible solution.

In component1.ts:- try to call navigate as following:

```js
this.router.navigate(['/operation', { firstNum: firstNum, secondNum: secondNum, answer: answer } ]);
```

---

**UPDATE #1**

`firstNum`, `secondNum`, `answer` are declared and initialized inside of for-loop, which is before your calling the `this.router.navigate()`.

What exactly you want to pass to Component2

---

**UPDATE #2**

Still can't understand purpose of the code, but try as following.

*component1.ts:-*

```js
var firstNum;
var secondNum;
var answer;

for (var i = 0; i < this.noQue; i++) { 
  firstNum = Math.floor((Math.random() * divider));
  secondNum = Math.floor((Math.random() * divider));

  if (this.operation == 1) {
    answer = firstNum + secondNum;
  }
  else if (this.operation == 2) {
   answer = firstNum - secondNum;
  }
  else if (this.operation == 3) {
    answer = firstNum * secondNum;
  }

  this.answers.push(answer);
  this.answers1.push(answer);
  this.que.push({ firstNum, secondNum });
  this.ques.push({ firstNum, secondNum });
}

console.log('que---', this.que)
console.log('ans---', this.answers)

this.router.navigate(['/operation', { firstNum: firstNum, secondNum: secondNum, answer: answer } ]);
```

*Component2.ts:-*

```js
export class OperationComponent implements OnInit {
  public f: number;
  public fa: number;
  public answer: number;
  que:[]; // What for?

  constructor(private route: ActivatedRoute) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.f = parseInt(this.route.snapshot.paramMap.get("firstNum"));
    this.fa = parseInt(this.route.snapshot.paramMap.get("secondNum"));
    this.answer = parseInt(this.route.snapshot.paramMap.get("answer"));
  }
```

Comment: All data's are getting passed to component 2(I can see it on console) but only the first value is displayed

Comment: Please look at UPDATE #1&2

Comment: [What should I do when someone answers my question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)

Answer (score 0):

you are pushing `this.que.push({ firstNum, secondNum });` firstNum and secondNum into the same array right?

So why don't you send the whole array to the next page so that you can access it there the way you want it.

The way you are currently doing will and can lead you into code mess and possible lock in the future when it comes to passing multiple parameters when in need.

So,

```
this.router.navigate(['/operation', { que: this.que, answer: answer } ]);
```

this kinda approach would be beneficial.

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve the same in two steps:

**Step 1:**
send query param while navigating from one page to another page.

```
this.router.navigate(['/operation'], {queryParams: {firstNum: firstNum, SecondNum: SecondNum, answer : answer }});
```

**Step 2:**
In another component, you can get the value of query param via the `ActivatedRoute` module.

```
this.firstNum= this._Activatedroute.snapshot.queryParams['firstNum']; 
this.SecondNum= this._Activatedroute.snapshot.queryParams['SecondNum']; 
this.answer = this._Activatedroute.snapshot.queryParams['answer'];
```

**Note:** for using the `ActivatedRoute` module you have to inject it in your component.

```
 constructor( private _Activatedroute: ActivatedRoute)
```